# Using FCM to send PushKit Notifications

Tags: android, ios

I would like to know if `FCM` has started supporting to send `PushKit` notifications for `iOS` devices. If they are not, then can I get to know other approach which can be send `VOIP` notifications to devices(iOS/Android)?
All your suggestions are very much appreciated. Thank you.